Tracing edges of pixels in a mask
I have a mask bitmap consisting of a 2D array of 1 and 0 values, which I would like to convert to a polygon, where the polygon traces exactly around the edges of the pixels. The regions in the mask can also contain holes. The output polygons should not contain any holes. An example is the following, where I would like to obtain the vertices of the polygon (the thick lines here).

Is there an easy to implement algorithm or set of algorithms for doing this?

Here is a rudimentary approach, that checks neighbors:


const ctx = document.querySelector('#drawing').getContext('2d');

const matrix = [
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
];

renderGrid(ctx, matrix, { squareSize: 40, borderWidth: 1, outlineWidth: 4, padding: 10 });

function renderGrid(ctx, matrix, { squareSize = 40, borderWidth = 1, outlineWidth = 4, padding = 10 }) {
  const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;  // Handle high DPI screens
  const rows = matrix.length;
  const cols = matrix[0].length;
  const gridWidth = squareSize * cols;
  const gridHeight = squareSize * rows;
  const width = gridWidth + padding * 2;
  const height = gridHeight + padding * 2;

  // Set canvas size based on device pixel ratio
  ctx.canvas.width = width * dpr;
  ctx.canvas.height = height * dpr;

  // Scale the drawing based on the pixel ratio to ensure clarity
  ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
  ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

  // Adjust size in CSS (logical pixels)
  ctx.canvas.style.width = `${width}px`;
  ctx.canvas.style.height = `${height}px`;

  // Calculate offsets for centering
  const xOffset = padding;
  const yOffset = padding;

  // Clear the canvas first
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  // Draw the grid lines with offsets
  drawGrid(ctx, { gridWidth, gridHeight, rows, cols, squareSize, strokeStyle: 'black', borderWidth, xOffset, yOffset });

  // Draw the squares with offsets
  drawSquares(ctx, { matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, xOffset, yOffset });
  
  // Draw the outlines with offsets
  drawOutlines(ctx, { matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, outlineWidth, strokeStyle: 'black', xOffset, yOffset });
}

function drawSquares(ctx, { matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, xOffset, yOffset }) {
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      if (matrix[row][col] === 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla(120, 100%, 80%, 0.8)';
        ctx.fillRect(col * squareSize + xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset, squareSize, squareSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawOutlines(ctx, { matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, outlineWidth, strokeStyle, xOffset, yOffset }) {
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  const directions = [
    { dx: 0, dy: -1 },  // top
    { dx: 0, dy: 1 },   // bottom
    { dx: 1, dy: 0 },   // right
    { dx: -1, dy: 0 }   // left
  ];

  function isInBounds(row, col) {
    return row > -1 && row < rows && col > -1 && col < cols;
  }

  function getNeighbor({ row, col, dx, dy }) {
    const neighborRow = row + dy;
    const neighborCol = col + dx;
    return isInBounds(neighborRow, neighborCol) ? matrix[neighborRow][neighborCol] : null;
  }

  // Check for outlining each "group" of 1s
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      const type = matrix[row][col];
      
      if (type !== 1) continue;  // Skip if the current cell is not part of the group
      
      ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
      ctx.lineWidth = outlineWidth;

      for (const { dx, dy } of directions) {
        const neighbor = getNeighbor({ row, col, dx, dy });

        // Skip drawing if the neighbor is the same type
        if (neighbor === type) {
          continue;
        }

        // Calculate start and end points dynamically based on dx and dy
        const startX = col * squareSize + xOffset + (dx === 1 ? squareSize : 0);
        const startY = row * squareSize + yOffset + (dy === 1 ? squareSize : 0);
        const endX = startX + (dx !== 0 ? 0 : squareSize);
        const endY = startY + (dy !== 0 ? 0 : squareSize);

        // Draw the outline
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
        ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawGrid(ctx, { gridWidth, gridHeight, rows, cols, squareSize, strokeStyle, borderWidth, xOffset, yOffset }) {
  // Draw the grid lines
  ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

  // Horizontal lines (draw between rows)
  for (let row = 1; row < rows; row++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset);
    ctx.lineTo(gridWidth + xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // Vertical lines (draw between columns)
  for (let col = 1; col < cols; col++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(col * squareSize + xOffset, yOffset);
    ctx.lineTo(col * squareSize + xOffset, gridHeight + yOffset);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  // Draw the outer grid border
  ctx.strokeRect(xOffset, yOffset, gridWidth, gridHeight);
}
#drawing {
  border: thin dashed red;
}
<canvas id="drawing"></canvas>



You can compute the merged polygon by create a unique set of points using sorted edges.


const ctx = document.querySelector('#drawing').getContext('2d');

const matrix = [
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
];

renderGrid(ctx, matrix, {
  squareSize: 40,
  borderWidth: 1,
  outlineWidth: 4,
  padding: 10
});

// Main entry point to render the grid and polygons
function renderGrid(ctx, matrix, { squareSize = 40, borderWidth = 1, outlineWidth = 4, padding = 10 }) {
  const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  const rows = matrix.length;
  const cols = matrix[0].length;
  const gridWidth = squareSize * cols;
  const gridHeight = squareSize * rows;
  const width = gridWidth + padding * 2;
  const height = gridHeight + padding * 2;

  // Setup canvas with device pixel ratio for clarity
  setupCanvas(ctx, width, height, dpr);

  // Calculate offsets for centering
  const xOffset = padding;
  const yOffset = padding;

  // Clear the canvas first
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  // Draw the grid and squares
  drawGrid(ctx, { gridWidth, gridHeight, rows, cols, squareSize, strokeStyle: 'black', borderWidth, xOffset, yOffset });
  drawSquares(ctx, { matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, xOffset, yOffset });

  // Process and render polygons
  const edges = extractEdgesFromMatrix(matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, xOffset, yOffset);
  const sortedEdges = chainEdgesIntoLoops(edges);
  renderPolygons(ctx, sortedEdges, outlineWidth, 'black');
}

// Setup the canvas size and scaling
function setupCanvas(ctx, width, height, dpr) {
  ctx.canvas.width = width * dpr;
  ctx.canvas.height = height * dpr;
  ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);
  ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
  ctx.canvas.style.width = `${width}px`;
  ctx.canvas.style.height = `${height}px`;
}

// Extract edges from the matrix
function extractEdgesFromMatrix(matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, xOffset, yOffset) {
  const uniqueEdges = new Set();

  function toggleEdge(edge) {
    const key = edge.join(',');
    if (uniqueEdges.has(key)) {
      uniqueEdges.delete(key); // Remove shared edges
    } else {
      uniqueEdges.add(key); // Add new unique edge
    }
  }

  // Traverse the matrix and toggle edges based on neighbors
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      if (matrix[row][col] === 1) {
        const tl = [col * squareSize + xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset];
        const tr = [(col + 1) * squareSize + xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset];
        const bl = [col * squareSize + xOffset, (row + 1) * squareSize + yOffset];
        const br = [(col + 1) * squareSize + xOffset, (row + 1) * squareSize + yOffset];

        toggleEdge([tl, tr]);
        toggleEdge([bl, br]);
        toggleEdge([tl, bl]);
        toggleEdge([tr, br]);
      }
    }
  }

  const edgePoints = Array.from(uniqueEdges).map(edge => edge.split(',').map(Number));
  return edgePoints.map(points => [
    [points[0], points[1]], 
    [points[2], points[3]]
  ]);
}

// Chain edges into continuous loops (polygons)
function chainEdgesIntoLoops(edges) {
  const loops = [];

  while (edges.length > 0) {
    const currentLoop = [];
    let currentEdge = edges.shift();
    currentLoop.push(currentEdge);

    while (true) {
      const nextEdgeIndex = edges.findIndex(edge => pointsEqual(currentEdge[1], edge[0]));
      if (nextEdgeIndex === -1) break;

      const nextEdge = edges[nextEdgeIndex];
      currentLoop.push(nextEdge);
      currentEdge = nextEdge;
      edges.splice(nextEdgeIndex, 1);
    }

    loops.push(currentLoop);
  }

  return loops;
}

// Render the polygons
function renderPolygons(ctx, sortedEdges, outlineWidth, strokeStyle) {
  sortedEdges.forEach(polygonEdges => {
    const simplifiedEdges = simplifyCollinearEdges(polygonEdges);
    renderPolygon(ctx, simplifiedEdges, outlineWidth, strokeStyle);
  });
}

// Simplify collinear edges
function simplifyCollinearEdges(edges) {
  if (edges.length <= 1) return edges;

  const simplifiedEdges = [];
  let currentStart = edges[0][0];
  let currentEnd = edges[0][1];

  for (let i = 1; i < edges.length; i++) {
    const [nextStart, nextEnd] = edges[i];

    if (isCollinear(currentStart, currentEnd, nextStart, nextEnd)) {
      currentEnd = nextEnd;
    } else {
      simplifiedEdges.push([currentStart, currentEnd]);
      currentStart = nextStart;
      currentEnd = nextEnd;
    }
  }

  simplifiedEdges.push([currentStart, currentEnd]);
  return simplifiedEdges;
}

// Render a single polygon
function renderPolygon(ctx, edges, outlineWidth, strokeStyle) {
  if (edges.length === 0) return;

  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth = outlineWidth;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(edges[0][0][0], edges[0][0][1]);

  for (let i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
    const [, [x, y]] = edges[i];
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }

  ctx.stroke();
}

// Draw the grid lines and outer border
function drawGrid(ctx, { gridWidth, gridHeight, rows, cols, squareSize, strokeStyle, borderWidth, xOffset, yOffset }) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth = borderWidth;

  for (let row = 1; row < rows; row++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset);
    ctx.lineTo(gridWidth + xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (let col = 1; col < cols; col++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(col * squareSize + xOffset, yOffset);
    ctx.lineTo(col * squareSize + xOffset, gridHeight + yOffset);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  ctx.strokeRect(xOffset, yOffset, gridWidth, gridHeight);
}

// Draw the filled squares
function drawSquares(ctx, { matrix, rows, cols, squareSize, xOffset, yOffset }) {
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
      if (matrix[row][col] === 1) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla(120, 100%, 80%, 0.8)';
        ctx.fillRect(col * squareSize + xOffset, row * squareSize + yOffset, squareSize, squareSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

// Utility functions

function pointsEqual(p1, p2) {
  return p1[0] === p2[0] && p1[1] === p2[1];
}

function isCollinear(start1, end1, start2, end2) {
  return (
    (start1[0] === end1[0] && start1[0] === start2[0] && start1[0] === end2[0]) ||  
    (start1[1] === end1[1] && start1[1] === start2[1] && start1[1] === end2[1])  
  );
}
#drawing {
  border: thin dashed red;
}
<canvas id="drawing"></canvas>




This task is pretty straightforward, but it requires a few steps:

Scan all the pixels in the image from top to bottom (major) and left to right. Consider the top edge of the pixel and the pixel above.
When you encounter a boundary (pixel is different from the one above) that hasn't been traced already, trace the outline of the connected shape using length-1 segments.
Always trace in a clockwise direction around the filled region.  When you start tracing at a top boundary, it's an object.  Orient to the right.  When you start tracing at a bottom boundary, it's a hole.  Orient to the left.
When you finish tracing a hole, look up from the left point of the bottom boundary you started at to find the hole or object boundary above it. This will already have been traced.  Break the two paths and connect with vertical segments to create a single path.
When you're done, you will have outlines without holes for all of the objects in the image.  Hopefully there's only one.  Pick the one you want or whatever.
Compress the path by combining adjacent segments that go in the same direction into single lines.

If you need detail about any one of these steps, you should ask a separate question and link back to this one, since going into detail about how to do each step is too big for a single answer.

I have a different approach which seems rather robust. The idea is to consider the first unprocessed pixel in the mask. We build a list of line segments around the pixel in clockwise direction, where the segments are described by a starting coordinate and a direction (left, right, up, down).
We then iterate through the list of segments. If a segment has an unprocessed pixel in the mask on either side, we replace the segment with three others which trace around the edge of this new pixel. The pixel is marked as processed. By repeatedly doing this replacement, we build a set of segments around contiguous pixel groups. This routine also acts to make sure there are no holes within the output region.
At the end there can be segments where we go in one direction and immediately back in the previous. These are removed by a simple scan.
We can then trivially convert the set of segments into a polygon, optimizing out points which are in the same direction.
Example Python code to implement this is below.
import numpy as np

def makePolygons(mask):
    """Return a set of polygons from the mask bounding the >0 pixels

    Returns:
    [ [(x11,y11), (x12,y12)...], [[(x21,y21),...]] ]
    """

    # unprocessed pixels are set to be -1, so we can keep track of the
    # output polygons as >1
    msk = np.where(mask>0, -1, 0)

    # Make a list of line segments around a pixel
    # Each segment consists of (initial_y, initial_x, direction)

    # DIRECTIONS
    #   1 ->  
    #   ----- 2
    #/\ |   | |
    # | |   | V 
    # 4 |   |
    #   -----
    #   <- 3

    # If a segment lies next to an unprocessed mask pixel, we can
    # replace the segment with three which also encompass the pixel

    RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT, UP = 1, 2, 3, 4
    deltadirn = {RIGHT: (0,1), DOWN: (-1,0), LEFT: (0,-1), UP: (1,0)}
    yw, xw = msk.shape

    polys = []
    polyidx = 1   # keep track of which pixels assigned to which poly
    while True:
        # find the next unprocessed pixel to start
        idx0 = np.where(msk<0)
        if len(idx0[0]) == 0:
            # all done, so exit
            break
        y0, x0 = idx0[0][0], idx0[1][0]

        # initial segments around starting pixel
        segs = [
            (y0, x0, UP), (y0+1,x0, RIGHT),
            (y0+1,x0+1, DOWN), (y0,x0+1, LEFT)]
        msk[y0,x0] = polyidx

        iseg = 0
        while iseg < len(segs):
            y0, x0, dirn = segs[iseg]

            newseg = None
            if dirn == RIGHT:
                # segment is rightward (+x)
                if y0 < yw and msk[y0,x0]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,UP), (y0+1,x0,RIGHT), (y0+1,x0+1,DOWN)]
                    msk[y0,x0] = polyidx
                elif y0 > 0 and msk[y0-1,x0]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,DOWN), (y0-1,x0,RIGHT), (y0-1,x0+1,UP)]
                    msk[y0-1,x0] = polyidx
            elif dirn == DOWN:
                # segment is downward (-y)
                if x0 < xw and msk[y0-1,x0]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,RIGHT), (y0,x0+1,DOWN), (y0-1,x0+1,LEFT)]
                    msk[y0-1,x0] = polyidx
                elif x0 > 0 and msk[y0-1,x0-1]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,LEFT), (y0,x0-1,DOWN), (y0-1,x0-1,RIGHT)]
                    msk[y0-1,x0-1] = polyidx
            elif dirn == LEFT:
                # segment is leftward (-x)
                if y0 < yw and msk[y0,x0-1]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,UP), (y0+1,x0,LEFT), (y0+1,x0-1,DOWN)]
                    msk[y0,x0-1] = polyidx
                elif y0 > 0 and msk[y0-1,x0-1]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,DOWN), (y0-1,x0,LEFT), (y0-1,x0-1,UP)]
                    msk[y0-1,x0-1] = polyidx
            elif dirn == UP:
                # segment is upward (+y)
                if x0 > 0 and msk[y0,x0-1]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,LEFT), (y0,x0-1,UP), (y0+1,x0-1,RIGHT)]
                    msk[y0,x0-1] = polyidx
                elif x0 < xw and msk[y0,x0]<0:
                    newseg = [(y0,x0,RIGHT), (y0,x0+1,UP), (y0+1,x0+1,LEFT)]
                    msk[y0,x0] = polyidx

            if newseg is not None:
                # replace segment with new segments
                segs = segs[:iseg] + newseg + segs[iseg+1:]
            else:
                # move to next otherwise
                iseg += 1

        # clean up line segments where we go in one direction, then
        # back again
        i = 0
        while i<len(segs):
            d1 = segs[i][2]
            d2 = segs[(i+1)%len(segs)][2]
            if( (d1==LEFT and d2==RIGHT) or (d1==RIGHT and d2==LEFT) or
                (d1==UP and d2==DOWN) or (d1==DOWN and d2==UP) ):
                del segs[i]
                del segs[i % len(segs)]
                if i > 0:
                    i -= 1
            else:
                i += 1

        # move any with the same direction at end to start to
        # maximimize runs
        while segs[0][2] == segs[-1][2]:
            segs.insert(0, segs.pop())

        # turn line segments into a polygon
        poly = []
        lastdir = None
        for seg in segs:
            d = deltadirn[seg[2]]
            endpt = (seg[0]+d[0], seg[1]+d[1])
            if lastdir == seg[2]:
                # if we go in the same direction, replace last point
                poly[-1] = endpt
            else:
                poly.append(endpt)
            lastdir = seg[2]

        polys.append(poly)
        polyidx += 1

    print(msk)
    return polys

def main():
    mask = np.array([
        [0,1,1,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,0,1],
        [0,1,0,1,0,0],
        [0,1,1,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,0],
    ], dtype=np.int16)

    polys = makePolygons(mask)

    for i, poly in enumerate(polys)
        for p in poly:
            print('%g,%g' % tuple(p))
            print()

